# Angular 4 Server Side Rendering ngx-bootstrap carousel makes response hang

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering

So I'm trying to implement server side rendering on my angular 4 website and I think I'm pretty close. I have gotten all routes to render server side except for 1 specific route and the default route. The routes that do not work are /home, /anythingthatisntdefined, and (no route at all loads, but does not server side render the home page).

So the no route, just isn't getting picked up by my catch all route... the anything that isn't defined I'm assuming the server is not correctly processing the default route... and the /home route not loading, just doesn't make sense to me. Any tips?

Here is my server.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { platformServer, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory';
import * as express from 'express';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

const PORT = 4000;

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

let template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  console.log('url: ', options.req.url);
  const opts = { document: template, url: options.req.url };

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
    .then(html => callback(null, html));
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src')

app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log('caught by *');
  res.render('../dist/index.html', {
    req: req,
    res: res
  });
});
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}!`);
});
```

Here is my router

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './services/services.component';
import { ResourcesComponent } from './resources/resources.component';
import { ChurchesComponent } from './churches/churches.component';
import { GetAQuoteComponent } from './get-a-quote/get-a-quote.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'services',
    component: ServicesComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'resources',
    component: ResourcesComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'churches',
    component: ChurchesComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'get-a-quote',
    component: GetAQuoteComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**', 
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, I figured out why the one route/ random routes weren't loading. The ngx-bootstrap carousel (which I had on my home route) has an interval that needs to be disabled server side. Otherwise the route will hang forever and never load.

Reference: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/1353

And last, the fact of the no route not working was because of my static assets route which was intercepting the request before my express.get was.